# Google Tag manager - Get parent of element in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

In a custom javascript variable, how can you get the parent element of the clicked element?

```
<div>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

For instance, I want to go get the content of the `<H2>` when I click the `<a>` to log Lorem Ipsum when the `<a>` is clicked.

Comment: The parent element of the anchor tag is the `div`, not the `h2`.

Comment: Yeah, step one would be to get the div element, and then I could drop down to the h2 child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the Click Element variable works great here. It was weird, I was using it in '' and that made it return only the url. But you can use it like a this

```
function(){
    var title = jQuery({{Click Element}}).parent().find('h2').html();

    return title;
}
```

Comment: my god. i chased around after complicated solutions forever, when this would have worked all along. thank you

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question but while searching for this exact problem myself, I found [this really helpful link](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/capturing-the-correct-element-in-google-tag-manager) with a solution.

You can add custom variables. To do this, in Google Tag Manager go to `Variables`, under `User-Defined Variables` click on `New`. Select `Variable Type` of `Custom JavaScript`, name it `Find Closest` and past the following code:

```js
function() {
  return function(target, selector) {
    while (!target.matches(selector) && !target.matches('body')) {
      target = target.parentElement;
    }
    return target.matches(selector) ? target : undefined;
  }
}
```

Add another JavaScript Variable for your specific case. Something like:

```js
function() {
    var parentElement = {{Find Closest}}({{Click Element}}, 'div'),
        childElement = typeof parentElement !== 'undefined' ? parentElement.querySelector('h2') : undefined;
    return typeof childElement !== 'undefined' ? childElement.innerText : undefined;
}
```

*Note: You can add a polyfill for `matches` for older browers.*

Answer (score -2):

With Jquery, you can do something like this

```
$('a').click(function(){
 var h2Content = $(this).siblings('h2').text();
 console.log(h2Content);
});
```

Be carefull, this code will put a click event handler on all  tags.

Comment: This is within Google Tag Manager. You can't bind a click beforehand.

Comment: Thats not true. You can bind through custom HTML. However it is best to retrieve the value through using jquery and the click element as you answered.