# GTM - Get 3rd parent of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

In a custom javascript variable, how can you get the 3rd parent element of the clicked element and then get down to a child?
I need to get the value of price (437,00) from this example.

[image]

Selector of clicked button: `#addToCartForm3V1061551 > button > span`

Selector of price that I need to get:    `body > main > div.main__inner-wrapper.js-main-inner-wrapper > div.main__content > div.page-content > div.page-content-main > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.owl-wrapper-outer > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > a > div > div.product-teaser__details.product-teaser--price-discount > div > div.product-teaser__bottom > div.product-teaser__price-block > div.product-teaser__price > span.price-without-discount`

I've tried variants of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44316348/10363442
But no luck ...

```
function(){
    var title = jQuery({{Click Element}}).parent().find('h2').html();

    return title;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should show you how to target the element, but depending on what you are trying to achieve, you will likely need to bind to an event as your starting point and obviously take further action ...

Using jQuery ...

```js
var parentElem = jQuery('.add_to_cart_form .btn-primary').closest('.product-teaser__bottom');

var data = jQuery('.price-without-discount', parentElem).text();

console.log(data);

(function($){

  var btn = $('.add_to_cart_form .btn-primary');
  btn.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var parentElem = $(this).closest('.product-teaser__bottom');
    var data = $('.price-without-discount', parentElem).text();
    console.log(data);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-teaser__bottom">
    <div class="product-teaser__price-block">
        <div class="product-teaser__price-without-discount"></div>
        <div class="product-teaser__price">
            <span class="price-without-discount">437,00</span>
            <span class="product-teaser__price-currency">CZK</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-teaser__add-to-cart">
        <form class="add_to_cart_form">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Test Button</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using vanilla javascript ...

```js
/**
 * Element.closest Polyfill
 *
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest
 */
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
  Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
}
if (!Element.prototype.closest) {
  Element.prototype.closest = function(s) {
    var el = this;
    do {
      if (Element.prototype.matches.call(el, s)) return el;
      el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
    } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1);
    return null;
  };
}

var btnElem = document.querySelector('.add_to_cart_form .btn-primary');
var parentElem = btnElem.closest('.product-teaser__bottom');
var data = parentElem.querySelector('.price-without-discount').textContent;

console.log(data);

btnElem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var parentElem = this.closest('.product-teaser__bottom');
  var data = parentElem.querySelector('.price-without-discount').textContent;
  console.log(data);
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="product-teaser__bottom">
    <div class="product-teaser__price-block">
        <div class="product-teaser__price-without-discount"></div>
        <div class="product-teaser__price">
            <span class="price-without-discount">437,00</span>
            <span class="product-teaser__price-currency">CZK</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-teaser__add-to-cart">
        <form class="add_to_cart_form">
            <button stype="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Test Button</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this pointed me in the right direction!
I made changes to reflect Google Tag Manager environment and the fact, that in the DOM tree there is class "price-without-discount" twice. This is final code snippet: 

`var title1 = jQuery({{Click Element}}).closest('.product-teaser__bottom');
var price = jQuery(title1).find('.price-without-discount').last().text();`