# CSS selector with Google Tag Manager on button[name=]

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

i have a click trigger (All Elements) in google tag manager with click element -> matches css selector - button[name=checkout]. However, the trigger does not work for the span content inside the button tag. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```
<button type="submit" name="checkout" class="Cart__Checkout Button Button--primary Button--full">
          <span>Zum Checkout</span>
          <span class="Button__SeparatorDot"></span>
          <span>99,95 €</span>
</button>
```

Thx!

Comment: Have you tried getting the parent of the clicked element using a JS variable? [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315069/google-tag-manager-get-parent-of-element-in-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You've missed quotes.

Also, no need to use GTM to test your CSS selectors. Always do it in the dev tools like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution button[name=checkout], button[name=checkout] * works in my case